# casperjs can't click on reddit.com

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

my casperjs click is working fine in most web site, but when i try to click something on reddit, it wont click.

```
casper.start();
casper.then(function (){
  this.open("http://reddit.com");
});

casper.then(function(){
        this.sendKeys("[name='user']", 'someusername');
        this.sendKeys("[name='passwd']", 'somepassword');
        this.click("[id='rem-login-main']");
        this.click(x('//*[@id="login_login-main"]/div[3]/button'))
});
casper.run();
```

the sendkeys function is working well, but both click function is not workin, please help!

Comment: How do you know that it's not working? I see no validation code such as waiting and screenshot taking.

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: hi artjom, sorry i didnt write the wait and screenshot because i want the code easier to read. and here is the problem, when i run a this.click, it wont click, but if i add a keypress event "space", the keypress will click that button, so what is that really mean?

Comment: It means that the click handler is implemented in such a way that CasperJS' procedure doesn't trigger it. Sometimes something else works, like focusing the form and sending an "Enter" keypress event.

Comment: thanks artjom, one more question.. I am sending the following command: "document.querySelector("[class='submit']").click();" within the chrome console, it can click anything inside reddit.com; so do you know any different between clicking inside chrome console and casperjs? or is there any thing like a click focus? thanks

Comment: You can do the same way of clicking in CasperJS as you currently do in Chrome (if you're using PhantomJS 2.x). Remember that it must be done inside of `casper.evaluate()`

Answer (score 0):

Find the below code and its working

```
casper.test.begin("Opening Reddit page", 1, function suite(test) {

    var x = require('casper').selectXPath;//required if we detect an element using xpath
    casper.start();

    casper.viewport(1024, 768).then(function () {
        this.open("http://reddit.com");
        this.wait(5000)
    });

    casper.then(function () {
        this.sendKeys("[name='user']", 'username');
        this.sendKeys("[name='passwd']", 'password');
        this.click("[id='rem-login-main']");
        this.click(x(".//*[@id='login_login-main']/div[3]/button"));
    });

    casper.wait(5000)

    casper.then(function () {
        this.test.assertExists(x(".//*[@id='header-img']"), "Confirmed that page has successfully loaded");
    });

    casper.run(function () {
        test.done();
    });
});
```

Comment: hi prateek, i tried your code, and i added a screenshot before casper.run, and the value of username and password is entered, but it is not clicking the login button. If it is successfully clicked, it should pop up a wrong password. would you mind adding "casper.capture('login_button.png');" and see if your casperjs appear the wrong password?

Comment: According to you the scenario is, you are entering wrong password and expecting a pop up! right?. The just change your question so that we can get the complete picture